# Fade In Out CSS animation into another animation

Tags: css, animation, css-animations, fade, keyframe

I'm trying to create a loading animation for my weather app.
I want to parade across a div for 10s in a loop a series of images that will come one by one and be replaced by the next. I managed to do this without any problem, but now I'd like to create a fade in-out transition for each image.

Here is my attempt:

```
animation: changeEmojis 9s infinite linear;

        @keyframes changeEmojis {
            0% {
                background-image: url("src/emojis/sun.png");
                animation: fadeInOut 1s;
            } 11% {
                background-image: url("src/emojis/cloud.png");
                animation: fadeInOut 1s;
            } 22% {
                background-image: url("src/emojis/cloud-with-rain.png");
                animation: fadeInOut 1s;
            } 33% {
                background-image: url("src/emojis/thunder-cloud-and-rain.png");
                animation: fadeInOut 1s;
            } 44% {
                background-image: url("src/emojis/wind.png");
                animation: fadeInOut 1s;
            } 55% {
                background-image: url("src/emojis/cloud-with-snow.png");
                animation: fadeInOut 1s;
            } 66% {
                background-image: url("src/emojis/rainbow.png");
                animation: fadeInOut 1s;
            } 77% {
                background-image: url("src/emojis/comet.png");
                animation: fadeInOut 1s;
            } 88% {
                background-image: url("src/emojis/full-moon.png");
                animation: fadeInOut 1s;
            } 100% {
                background-image: url("src/emojis/sun.png");
                animation: fadeInOut 1s;
            }
        }

        @keyframes fadeInOut {
            0% {
                opacity: 0;
            } 50% {
                opacity: 1;
            } 100% {
                opacity: 0;
            }
        }
```

Basically I tried to put an animation inside the animation. But it doesn't work.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you show us what your fadeinout keyframes setup is? You are right, animation isn't an animatable property, but opacity is so you should be able build that in.

Comment: @AHaworth the keyframe is here, you have to scroll down the code ^^

Answer (score 0):

As you have seen, `animation` is not itself animatable, but nothing stops you from specifying both animations at once. The `animation` property allows you to specify multiple animations separated by a comma.

```css
.weather {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  animation: changeEmojis 6s infinite linear, fadeInOut 2s linear -1s infinite;
  background-size: contain;
}

/* https://www.flaticon.com/packs/weather-163 */
@keyframes changeEmojis {
  0% {
    background-image: url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/1163/1163763.png');
  } 33% {
    background-image: url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/1163/1163730.png');
  } 67% {
    background-image: url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/1163/1163764.png');
  } 100% {
    background-image: url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/1163/1163763.png');
  } 
}

@keyframes fadeInOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  } 50% {
    opacity: 1;
  } 100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="weather"></div>
```

The key here is to specify the durations such that they overlap in the way you want. In my example, I just used three weather icons over 6 seconds, meaning the `fadeInOut` animation has to happen every 2 seconds. The -1 second delay ensures the animations starts at `opacity: 1`.

---

An alternative approach is to bake `fadeInOut` into the `changeEmojis` animation by adding opacity breakpoints in-between the ones you currently have defined. That would be a bit more explicit, but not as composable.